# Sidebar toggle in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have one sidebar in asp.net master page which I want to hide on a button click. It works but on page load it displays again so i want to hide that sidebar till user click on that button to display it. Anyone have solution for this then please tell me as soon as possible...

Comment: Where is your code? Post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that. You need to try something like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show").click(function(){ // #show = button id
        $(".sidebar").toggle(); //.sidebvar = class of sidebar
    });
});
</script>

<div class="sidebar" style="display:none;"></div>
<button id="show" name="show" >Show</button>
```

This is just an example you can share what you have tried so far to give you exact solution to your problem.

Comment: But I want to use this for user's login activity.For various users, they can display or hide the sidebar based on their session.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that just using jquery and CSS as these events are triggered when the page is loaded and gets reset every time the page is reloaded.

To hide and show the side panel dynamically, you can

Option 1:
change the URL of the page every time the button is clicked

```
www.yourwebsite.com?panel=show
www.yourwebsite.com?panel=hide
```

Option 2:
You can use any of the server side languages to change the session variables upon button click. Some of then are PHP, JSP of ASP.net

Comment: If you know any of server-side languages (asp.net in your case), then you can create a session attribute for the panel. Set it to true if you want to show it else set to false.

Comment: Also it would be great if you could share your project requirements. I mean, if you are building it for a school project or full-fledged website to be deployed on the internet.